# calling c++ DLL from android application

Tags: android, c++

i create one dll in visual studio(i didn't use any win_API functions).i want to call this dlll from android i generated .apk file but while running this file i an facing this error.

"java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load Testdll1 from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/c, /system/lib]]]: findLibrary returned null
"

please advise me.

Ths

Comment: DLL as libraries are not supported by Android. Only .SO files.

Comment: ths for your quick reply.i am using windows operarting system is there any way to create .so file from windows os.

Comment: Yes, refer [Android NDK](https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html) documentation.

Answer (score 2):

DLLs run on Windows. They are not cross-platform. In order to run C++ on Android, you must use the [Android NDK](https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html) to compile your native code. You may find the details on this process [here](https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html#GetStarted).

Answer (score 1):

I think *.so can be used on Android, so you need to compile the library into *.so binary with gcc or clang rather than dll with msvc.

Answer (score 0):

DLL is used on windows, not on Android.

You can download [Android NDK for windows](https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html), read ndk example, then modify your code.